# Concat of count and group concat and order by

Tags: mysql

I'm having a bit of trouble of figuring to get things from db in a rather weird way. Say I have next table

```
ID  |   Rating
229 |   3
229 |   2
229 |   4
229 |   2
240 |   3
233 |   1
233 |   4
233 |   1
233 |   5
229 |   4
240 |   4
```

I need to result to look like

```
229 |   4,3,2   |   2,1,2
240 |   4,3     |   1,1
233 |   5,4,1   |   1,1,2
```

Basically, I need 2nd column to be list of all unique scores in desc order for this id and 3rd column needs to be comma separated count of each of these unique scores, so like in example above, for first id, it will be 2,1,2 because that id got 2 ratings with score 4, 1 with score 3, and 2 with score 2. This needs to be in same order as things in 2nd column. I tried

```
select object_id, group_concat(concat(rating)) list, group_concat(qty)
from (
select object_id, rating, count(rating) qty
from wp_fb_ratings
group by rating, object_id
order by rating desc
) n
group by object_id
```

Which does what I need, except it completely ignores order by and returns

```
229 |   3,2,4   |   1,2,2
233 |   1,4,5   |   2,1,1
240 |   3,4     |   1,1
```

What is workaround for this? Or maybe it should be done in some other way?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need it this way?

Comment: If you only run the inner select, is it ordered then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want a subquery to calculate the count, before doing the final aggregation:

```
select id, group_concat(score order by score desc) as scores,
       group_concat(cnt order by score desc) as counts
from (select id, score, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      group by id, score
     ) t
group by id;
```

For the tables in your example:

```
select object_id, group_concat(rating order by rating desc)as ratings,
       group_concat(qty order by rating desc) as qtys
from (select object_id, rating, count(rating) as qty
      from wp_fb_ratings
      group by rating, object_id
     ) t
group by object_id;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much all I need.

Comment: Say, is it possible to add something like default? These ratings can be from 1-5, so say for id 229 3rd column would return 0, 2, 1, 2, 0 (since there are no 5 and 1 ratings). That way, there would be no need in 2nd column.

Comment: @Flyer . . . I would suggest that you ask that as another question.